# Example of a discrete bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for every two points of that set there is another point between them of that set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, real-numbers

Can anyone give an example of a subset say $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that every point of that set is isolated i.e. for every $x \in A$  there exist a neighborhood say $N(x)$ containing x such that $N(x) \cap A = \{x\} $ and for any two points say $x,y\in A$ there exist $z\in A$ such that $x<z<y$.
Thanks in advance. **note that A should have at least two elements**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same idea as Dunston's answer.  Take the set $A$ of all the midpoints of removed intervals in the construction of the Cantor middle-thirds set.
Each point $a\in A$ is isolated, since the removed interval interval $J$ of which it is the center has $J \cap A = \{a\}$.

---

[image: picture]

So $A$ consists of:
$1/2$, the center if $(1/3,2/3)$,
$1/6$, the center of $(1/9,2/9)$,
$5/6$, the center of $(7/9,8/9)$,
and so on.

The infinite set $A$ is countable.  The set of accumulation points of $A$ is the Cantor set, with cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: So in other words, it's the numbers whose ternary expansion starts with some finite number of 0's and 2's after the decimal point, followed by infinitely repeating 1.

Comment: @DanielSchepler ... that is a good description.

Comment: @GEdgar, please could you write in your answer which is the cardinality of the set $A$ and which is the cardinality of the set $DA$ of the accumulation points of $A$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Such a set absolutely does exist. I don't know if there's a brief description of such a set, but it's not too difficult to construct one recursively.

Below is just annoying notation required to make an intuitively clear concept somewhat precise.

Let $S = [0, 1] \cap D$ where $D$ is the set of dyadic rational numbers, and let $d_0=0, d_1=1, d_2=1/2, \ldots$ be an enumeration of $S$ (the exact enumeration is arbitrary, but sorting lexicographically first by reduced fraction denominator and then by increasing numerator is what I have in mind). We will construct, recursively, a sequence of positive real numbers $\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \ldots$ and an increasing function $f: S \to [0, 1]$ with the property that the closed intervals $\big[f(d_n)-\epsilon_n, f(d_n)+\epsilon_n\big]$ are all disjoint from each other.

With this setup, it should be obvious that this is possible. Define $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, and then $\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1$ are somewhat arbitrary as long as they add up to less than $1$. Let's define them to be both $1/4$.

Having defined $f(d_0), \ldots, f(d_{n-1})$ and $\epsilon_0, \ldots, \epsilon_{n-1}$, let $\{i_0, \ldots, i_n\} = \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$ be the indices so that $d_{i_0} < d_{i_1} < \cdots < d_{i_n}$, and some $i_k$ is equal to $n$. Select $f(d_n) \in \big(f(d_{i_{k-1}})+\epsilon_{i_{k-1}}, f(d_{i_{k+1}})-\epsilon_{i_{k+1}}\big)$, which exists by construction, and select $\epsilon_n$ to delineate a neighborhood of $f(d_n)$ which misses both $f(d_{i_{k-1}})+\epsilon_{i_{k-1}}$ and $f(d_{i_{k+1}})-\epsilon_{i_{k+1}}$ (this again exists by construction).

After infinitely many steps, $f$ is constructed, and $f(S)$ consists entirely of isolated points in $\mathbb R$ and is order-theoretically dense.

Comment: How do you know that after infinitely many steps the set is still isolated?

Comment: @jjagmath each point is isolated by construction. The set $f(S)$ certainly has accumulation points - that's unavoidable. But those accumulation points don't live in $f(S)$.

Comment: " each point is isolated by construction."? How can it be isolated by construction if the set is not finished at the moment of its construction? Consider the following construction: $x_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = \frac{1}{2}$, $x_3 = \frac{1}{3}$, etc. Each point is isolated in the moment of the construction, but after infinitely many steps $x_0$ is no longer isolated. (I know that this don't satisfies the other conditions of the problem, it's just an example that taking the "limit" doesn't preserve isolation).

Comment: @jjagmath I literally have, by construction, an open interval around each point that doesn't contain any other points of $f(S)$, even after the infinitely many steps are completed. I don't know how to make this any clearer to you.

Comment: When you define $f(d_n)$ there is no previously constructed points on the interval $\big(f(i_{k-1})+\epsilon_{i_{k-1}}, f(i_{k+1})-\epsilon_{i_{k+1}}\big)$ but how do you know that the following points won't fall in that interval?

Comment: @jjagmath because I constructed $f(d_n)$ to not fall in any of the previously delineated intervals. So $f(d_{n+N})$ for $N \gg 0$ will be constructed with the same constraint in mind with respect to $f(d_n)$.

Comment: Doh!, sorry. I see now. Why to use dyadic rationals?

Comment: Only because the enumeration I suggested has an intuitively clear "traverse between the comb spikes" behavior. It's purely an aesthetic preference.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, could you tell me why you wrote in your answer that $$f(d_n) \in \big(f(i_{k-1})+\epsilon_{i_{k-1}}, f(i_{k+1})-\epsilon_{i_{k+1}}\big)\;.$$ Should not you have written that $$f(d_n) \in \big(f(d_{i_{k-1}})+\epsilon_{i_{k-1}}, f(d_{i_{k+1}})-\epsilon_{i_{k+1}}\big)\;?$$

Comment: @Angelo thanks for the correction.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, you are welcome ! Please, could you tell me what is the cardinality of accumulation points of $f(S)$ ?

Comment: @Angelo $\overline{f(S)}$ will be an order-theoretically dense set which satisfies the Least Upper Bound property (despite being nowhere connected). Such a set must have the cardinality of continuum. Since the accumulation points are $\overline{f(S)}\setminus f(S)$ (no member of $f(S)$ is an accumulation point by construction), and $f(S)$ is countable, the accumulation points must also have the cardinality of continuum.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, when you say “order-theoretically dense set” do you mean a set $X$ with a (partial or total) order relation $R$ such that $\;\forall x,y \in X: xRy, \exists z \in X: xRz\land zRy$ ? Or do you mean another thing ?

Comment: @Angelo you got it right.